# Enable scripting in elasticsearch-2.2.0 using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy, lucene

I am using elasticsearch-2.2.0 version. I need to enable scripting using JAVA API.
Basically I want to create a node using NodeBuilder and enable scripting support.

I tried setting the properties "script.inline : true" and "script.indexed : true" as below :

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("script.inline", true).put("script.indexed", true).build();
```

but still it does not works.

Is there a way to enable scripting in elasticsearch-2.2.0 version using JAVA ?

Comment: Do you get any error in your logs?

Comment: Yes I am getting error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/plugins/AbstractPlugin
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you show which elasticsearch dependency you have in your pom.xml in the client code?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency> <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-lang-groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-expressions</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the logs before/after that stack trace?

Comment: There is no such relevant information in the log before or after stack trace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110135/discussion-between-shailendra-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17200) and it seems that when creating a local `NodeClient` the `lang-groovy` module is not loaded by default.

So you need to add another dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch.module</groupId>    
   <artifactId>lang-groovy</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```